# Android get screen usable size api 28

Tags: android, android-studio, statusbar

I've tried a lot of things like:

```
val wm = c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
val display = wm.defaultDisplay
val size = Point()
display.getSize(size)
screenHeight = size.y
```

In the end, the most versatile one across different device sizes is:

```
   val v = requireActivity().findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)
   v.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object: ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener{
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    v.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener (this)
                    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                    editor.putInt("usableScreenHeight", v.height)
                    editor.apply()
                }
            })
```

I've tested this on a few real devices too and it seems to works. However, in my Android Studio emulator, using Api 28 (it works with the same device and api 24 for instance), I get a bigger status bar like the one in the picture. The size I get via `viewTreeObserver` is the same one, but my content is shifted down because of the bigger status bar. Is my code wrong? Do I have a problem with my emulator? Did something change in `api 28`?

[image]